# Exception Handling not working

Tags: java, exception

I made an ATM program. I have a try catch that will ask for the user to type in their pin number. The pin number must be 5 digits. So the exception will check if it is 5 digits or not but the exception handling is not working. No matter what number I type in, it always says invalid number.

Here is my code the try catch is at the top of the program and the exception handling checkNumber is at the bottom of the program..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankMain
{
    private double availableBal = 80;
    private double totalBal = 100;
    private double availableBal2 = 480;
    private double totalBal2 = 500;
    private double availableBal3 = 80;
    private double totalBal3 = 100;
    ArrayList<Integer> cardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String error; // String the error from the exception
    {
        error = "error";
    }

    public void cardNumbers()
    {

        Scanner cards = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {

            System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");

            cardNum.add(input.nextInt());
            checkNumber();

        }

        catch (invalidNumber err)
        {

            System.out.println("Caught Error: " + err.getError());
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you! You're card number is " + cardNum);

        System.out.println("Type 'c' to go back to main menu.");
        String value = keyboard.next();

        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {
            menu();

        }

        else if (!keyboard.equals('c'))
        {

            System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");

        }

    }

    public void menu()
    {

        System.out.println("ATM Menu:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1 = Create Account");
        System.out.println("2 = Account Login");
        System.out.println("3 = Exit ATM");
        query();
    }

    public void startAtm()
    {
        menu();

    }

    public void drawMainMenu()
    {

        AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
        int selection;

        System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
        System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
        System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
        System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
        System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
        System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        selection = input.nextInt();

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            viewAccountInfo();
            break;
        case 2:
            withdraw();
            break;
        case 3:
            addFunds();
            break;
        case 4:
            AccountMain.selectAccount();
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
        }
    }

    public void viewAccountInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Account Information:");
        System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $" + totalBal);
        System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $" + availableBal);
        drawMainMenu();
    }

    public void viewAccountInfo2()
    {
        System.out.println("Account Information:");
        System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $" + totalBal2);
        System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $" + availableBal2);
        drawMainMenu();
    }

    public void deposit(int depAmount)
    {
        System.out.println("\n***Please insert your money now...***");
        totalBal = totalBal + depAmount;
        availableBal = availableBal + depAmount;
    }

    public void checkNsf(int withdrawAmount)
    {
        if (totalBal - withdrawAmount < 0)
            System.out.println("\n***ERROR!!! Insufficient funds in you accout***");
        else
        {
            totalBal = totalBal - withdrawAmount;
            availableBal = availableBal - withdrawAmount;
            System.out.println("\n***Please take your money now...***");
        }
    }

    public void addFunds()
    {
        int addSelection;

        System.out.println("Deposit funds:");
        System.out.println("1 - $20");
        System.out.println("2 - $40");
        System.out.println("3 - $60");
        System.out.println("4 - $100");
        System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        addSelection = input.nextInt();

        switch (addSelection)
        {
        case 1:
            deposit(20);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            deposit(40);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            deposit(60);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 4:
            deposit(100);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 5:
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void withdraw()
    {
        int withdrawSelection;

        System.out.println("Withdraw money:");
        System.out.println("1 - $20");
        System.out.println("2 - $40");
        System.out.println("3 - $60");
        System.out.println("4 - $100");
        System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        withdrawSelection = input.nextInt();

        switch (withdrawSelection)
        {
        case 1:
            checkNsf(20);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            checkNsf(40);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            checkNsf(60);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 4:
            checkNsf(100);
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        case 5:
            drawMainMenu();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void query()
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (input == 2)
        {

            BankMainPart2 main2 = new BankMainPart2();

            System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit card number.");
            BankMainPart2.loginCard(cardNum);

        }
        else if (input == 1)
        {

            cardNumbers();

        }

        else if (input == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

    public void checkingMenu()
    {

        AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
        int selection;

        System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
        System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
        System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
        System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
        System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
        System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        selection = input.nextInt();

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            viewAccountInfo2();
            break;
        case 2:
            withdraw();
            break;
        case 3:
            addFunds();
            break;
        case 4:
            AccountMain.selectAccount();
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
        }
    }

    private static void checkNumber() throws invalidNumber // run the check activation exception
    {
        if (String.valueOf(input).length() != 5)
        {
            throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Works!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BankMain myAtm = new BankMain();
        myAtm.startAtm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this program compiling at all?

Comment: I'm not sure `int` is a good type for a PIN, consider the PIN `00001`, which will have the value `1` and translate to a 1 digit string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are having three different instances of Scanner class.. That is what making the program confusing..

In the `compareNumber()` method, you are actually checking the value of `input`, which is an instance of Scanner.. It's better to use it like this: -

`checkNumber(input.nextInt())`

And add the number to the list in your `checkNumber(int num)` method..

Of course I am not saying that it is a good way of coding.. But it will solve your problem for the time being..

Else, there are so many issues with your code..

This is your try-catch block: -

```
        try {
            System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");
            cardNum.add(input.nextInt());
            checkNumber();
        } catch (invalidNumber err) {
            System.out.println("Caught Error: " + err.getError());
        }
```

And this is your `checkNumber()` method : -

```
private static void checkNumber() throws invalidNumber 
{
    if (String.valueOf(input).length() != 5) {
        throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Works!");
    }
}
```

Now you must see that you are using `input` as a parameter to `String.valueOf(input)`.

But you have declared 'input` as an instance of Scanner before your try-catch block..

```
    Scanner cards = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This code is in your `codeNumbers()` method..

So, clearly your `input` can never actually contain a user input, rather a `hashcode` representing the object `new Scanner(System.in)`.

So, its better that you pass the integer input from user to `checkNumber()` method..

******************** MODIFICATION Needed in Code..

So, your checkNumber()` will be modified as: -

```
    private static void checkNumber(int number) throws invalidNumber 
    {
        if (String.valueOf(number).length() != 5) {
            throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Works!");
        }
    }
```

And your call to this method in try-catch block will change to this: -

```
        try {
            System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            cardNum.add(number);
            checkNumber(number);
        } catch (invalidNumber err) {
            System.out.println("Caught Error: " + err.getError());
        }
```

Comment: Code seems to be running fine for me? and I can't use checkNumber(input.nextInt())

Comment: Well, in your question you said, it's not running fine.. And as from your code, you will face many problems.. You cannot operate on `input` as it is an instance of `Scanner`.. And when you read a number through Scanner, then the number is not stored in `scanner` instance but in the `scanner.nextInt()`

Comment: Apart from everything else, you Code is not compiling at all.. How can you say that code is working fine??

Comment: Thanks I figured out the problem and fixed it but you mentioned that a lot of my code is messy and it's not compiling... what do you mean? As I am new to the programming world and to java.. cause my program is working, I just ran it a couple times.

Comment: Then may be you didn't posted the complete code here.. Because I don't see an exception class for `invalidInput` you have thrown..  Also, you have dumped everything in a single class (Although that doesn't matter in the initial stages, but it is a huge design issue to worry about)..

Comment: Yeah I have 2 more classes that I didn't think was necessary to post here

Comment: So you think I should cut it off into smaller chunks?

Comment: Then its ok.. But don't worry about all the `messy code` part that you saw.. You will learn how to design your code properly as you gain experience.. It comes with that only..

Comment: @MattMcCarthy. Generally thats an ideal way to code.. Your methods should be small.. They should be `Cohesive`, i.e, they should concentrate only on single task.. And there are many more things. But as I said, forget about all these things as far as your code is working..

Comment: Quick question, how do I make a subclass?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet looks fine:

```
    if (String.valueOf(input).length() != 5)
    {
        throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
    }
    else
    {

        System.out.println("Works!");
    }
```

As long as you don't realize that `input` is **not** the `double` variable declared locally somewhere:

```
double input = keyboard.nextInt()
```

instead it's an instance of [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (!)

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)
```

And [`Scanner.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#toString%28%29) is certainly not the PIN you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks that `String.valueOf(input)` has a length of 5 characters. But `input` is not the number entered by the user. It's the object of type `Scanner` that is used to parse what the user enters. So the result of `String.valueOf(input)` is probably something like `java.util.Scanner@B09876`.

Comment: Kinda makes sense, what would I use then?

Comment: Make the `checkNumber()` method take its number to check as argument, and change the calling code to `int num = input.nextInt(); checkNumber(num); ...`

Comment: Okay that seems to be working, but now its asking me to enter the number twice